# plutext sample creates a xlsx file that is empty when opening using Numbers in MacOS

Tags: excel, numbers, docx4j

When creating an Excel using the example CreateSimpleSpreadsheet.java.
The created spreadsheet shows correctly the sample data in MacOS Excel (Ver 15.30 - 170107)
but when opening in MacOS using Numbers (ver 3.6.2 - 2577) the sheet is empty.

However, when opening in Excel under MacOS and then saving the sheet new and opening the new file using Numbers, the sheet is correctly displayed.

What is the cause for this ?
I need the created xlsx file opens correctly in Numbers under MacOS also

Answer (score 0):

Saving the XLSX in Excel 2010 adds a reference attribute to each cell, eg @r="A1".  Try adding that to the first cell, and B1 to the second.

Excel also makes other changes which don't matter, including @r=1 on the row, and using shared strings (as opposed to inline strings).  An easy way to see them is to use the Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool's compare files feature.  But that's for Windows...

**UPDATE NEXT MORNING**

Adding the reference attribute to each cell, eg @r="A1", is all that's required for iCloud Numbers (as of time of writing) to display cell contents.

https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/commit/05c368caca7dd404f8d39f83346a7980b6cfdcf1 adds those.